# What is a "copy c-or" in C++?

Tags: c++, terminology, vocabulary

I am came across a question *Which is better `i++` or `++i`*. 
Somebody said `++i` as it does not require copy c-or . *I just want to know what is a copy c-or and is it a disadvantage to use such a thing ?*

Comment: *c-or* stands for *constructor* and implies C++ rather than C.

Comment: This is not a duplicate; the question is, "What is a copy c-or?" This hasn't been asked before. According to Google, there is no mention of "copy c-or" in any other question on SO. While "copy c-or" doesn't seem to be commonly used when discussing C++, the OP probably *meant* to ask, "What is a copy **ctor**?" While that probably *would* be a duplicate, it's not a duplicate of the questions shown here.

Comment: @DanMoulding Ya i totally agree ...

Comment: Please provide a link to the question. I cannot find a question with the quoted title, and Google doesn't show any other questions with the term *copy c-or*.

Comment: Lesson to be learned from this: **duplicate** *doo' - pli - kit* (n.) 1. a copy exactly like an original. 2. anything corresponding in all respects to something else. Having a different key term in the question title does not make a similar question into a duplicate!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both "copy c-or" and "copy ctor" refer to the "copy constructor", which essentially refers to the object having to be copied.

The reason for this is that the post-increment operator increments the object in question, but also returns the original object in the expression, necessitating a copy.